# requests: post multipart/form-data

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, python-requests

My API:

```
class FileView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    def post(self, request):
        do something with request.FILES.dict().iteritems()
```

My [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) file:

```
try:
    headers = {
        'content-type': "multipart/form-data",
        'authorization': "Basic ZXNlbnRpcmVcYdddddddddddddd",
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }
    myfile = {"file": ("filexxx", open(filepath, "rb"))}

    response = requests.request("POST", verify=False, url=url, data=myfile, headers=headers)

    print(response.text)
except Exception as e:
    print "Exception:", e
```

Error:

**"Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"**

**What is right way to post the file?** Thanks

> > > requests.**version**
> > >       '2.10.0'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Removed 'content-type' from the headers, now it works

```
try:
    headers = {
        'authorization': "Basic ZXNlbnRpcmVcYdddddddddddddd",
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }
    myfile = {"file": ("filexxx", open(filepath, "rb"))}

    response = requests.request("POST", verify=False, url=url, data=myfile, headers=headers)

    print(response.text)
except Exception as e:
    print "Exception:", e
```

Comment: Let requests set the content-type. In the request headers, the value for `content-type='multipart/form-data; boundary=f0d7eb0b58c94f8ea3e665e28cffffdc'` where the boundary changes depending on the request.

Comment: Yes! when `content-type='multipart/form-data` browser adds this `boundary` parama while post request.So from python it is unnecessary totally! Anti-scraping tools like Distill-Networks etc. can use this param to detect python scraper easily.

Comment: Whatttttttttt! I've had to find this solution for 3 days.