# Upload file in angular2: Body (FormData) empty

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, form-data

I'm trying to upload a picture with Angular2 to my REST Service (Loopback).
The Loopback service works (tested with Postman) and accepts files with the x-www-form-urlencoded header.

Here's a simplified service method that sends the POST request:

```
public uploadFile(url : string, file: File): Observable<any> {
  let headers: Headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);

  let options: RequestOptionsArgs = { headers: headers };

  return this.http.post(url, formData, options)
  .map((res: any) => (res.text() != "" ? res.json() : {}));
}
```

Note that I've set the header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and send the formData containing the file in the body.

In Angular, up until the point where I http.post the request, the formData is populated with the file, the file content is present, everyting's fine:

[Data before Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GvtJ.png)

But in the request, the body is an empty object {}:

[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAuaL.png)

I assume, Angular is trying to do JSON.stringify(formData), at least, when I try this, I also get "{}" as output.

I've seen plenty of posts doing exactly the same (http.post(url, formData)). So what am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to give blob data to form?

Comment: Strange. I recently created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/R8yJpRWsE35pMpB1QeG3?p=preview) to answer a similar question and as you can see, just POSTing `formData` works. AFAIK, Angular DOES NOT automatically `JSON.stringify(formData)`. It will POST what you pass as is.

Comment: What is printed in the console?

Comment: I have done this the same way also. Are you 100% sure you 'file' is set to something?

Comment: What happens if you add a .subscribe to the post?

Comment: @AngularFrance Thanks for the Plunker! I compared it with my code and watched the output and it was so similar, also all the data was set, real strange! I tried removing the options from the request, because I figured that's the only aspect that differs between our solutions. And now it works. The request is then with multipart/form-data but interestengly my Loopback service does not care. However, it's still a bit frustrating. Would like to know why it doesn't work with urlencoded

Comment: @BenCameron Thx for your suggestions. 'file' was indeed set. The Observable is subscribed to in the caller method. That's not it. Could see the request go out, only with {} in the body.

Comment: @Christoph did you solve this problem? I'm stuck on this as well.

Answer (score 8):

Just remove `headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');` can solve problem.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270151/requests-post-multipart-form-data)

2017-08-24

Comment: This solved it for me, using Web Api 2 and Angular 4

Comment: Why is that? What's wrong with headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')?

Comment: Can you see my problem please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942899/upload-file-in-angular-5

Comment: Please see this package https://github.com/bleenco/ngx-uploader, the best file uploader I have fount. @OnnaB

Answer (score 1):

From this [How to inspect FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata) SO answer and this [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) outputing `FormData` in the console just results in a `{}`.

FormData can directly be used in a `for ... of` structure, instead of `entries()`: `for (var p of myFormData)` is equivalent to `for (var p of myFormData.entries())`.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution is to use base64 and convert it in back-end side:
`

```
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    let res;
    reader.onload = function () {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(config.serverUrl+"/index.php",
      {
         "file":reader.result}, options)
         .toPromise()
         .then(this.extractData)
         .catch(this.handleError);
      }
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
    };`
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i used formData.**set**() instead of formData.append()

please see example below :

```
 UploadFile(fileToUpload: File): Observable<boolean> {
     const endpoint = 'api/image/upload';
     var formData = new FormData();
     formData.set('file', fileToUpload);
     return this._http
     .post(endpoint, formData)
     .map(() => { return true; })
     .catch((e) => this.handleError(e));
 }
```